# How to exclude port ranges via ematch in Linux traffic control (tc)?

Tags: linux, filtering, ports, network-traffic

I am currently facing a trouble in my code.

Mainly, I emulate the connection between two computers, connected via an ethernet bridge (Raspberry Pi, Raspbian). So I am able to influence parameters of this connection (like bandwidth, latency and much more) via **tc qdisc**.
This works out fine, as you can see in the code down below.

**But now to my problem:**

---

I am also trying to exclude specific port ranges, what means ports that aren't influenced by my given parameters (latency etc..).

For that I created two prio bands. The prio band 0 (higher priority) handles my port exclusion (already in the parent root). 
Afterwards in prio band 1 (lower priority), I decline a latency via **netem**.

The whole data traffic will pass through my influenced prio band 1, the remaining (excluded data) will pass uninfluenced through prio band 0. 

I don't get kernel errors while executing my code! 
But I only receive ***`filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 basic`*** after typing ***`sudo tc filter show dev eth1`***. 
My match is not even mentioned. 
What did I wrong? 

Can you explain me why I don't get my excpected output?

---

***THIS IS MY CODE (in right order of executioning):***

## PARENT ROOT

`sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: prio bands 2 priomap 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

- This creates two priobands (1:1 and 1:2)

## BAND 0 [PORT EXCLUSION | port 100 - 800]

`sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:1 handle 10: tbf rate 512kbit buffer 1600 limit 3000`

- Creates a tbf (Token Bucket Filter) to set bandwidth

`sudo tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 handle 0x10 basic match "cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport lt 100) and cmp(u16 at 0 layer transport gt 800)" flowid 1:1`

- Creates a filter with specific handle, that excludes port 100 to 800 from the prioband 1 (the influenced data packets)

## BAND 1 [NET EMULATION]

`sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 20: tbf rate 1024kbit buffer 1600 limit 3000`

- Compare with tbf above

`sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 20:1 handle 21: netem delay 200ms`

- Creates via netem a delay of 200ms

[Here you can see my hierarchy as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHsNh.png)

> ***The question again:*** 
>   
> My filter match is not even mentioned. 
> What did I wrong? 
>   
> Can you explain me why I don't get my excpected output?

I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks for your efforts!

 ~rotsechs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have to neglect the missing output! Nevertheless, it works perfectly.

I established a SSH connection to my Ethernet Bridge (via MobaXterm). 
Afterwards I laid a delay of 400ms on it. The console inputs slowed down as expected. 

Finally I created the filter and excluded the port range from 20 to 24 (SSH has port 22). 
The delay of my SSH connection disappeared immediately!

Comment: any chance you could post the basics of your final scripts in this answer?